# failed to push application - Error performing Cloud foundry - 502 bad Gateway

Tags: spring, maven, cloud-foundry

I try to push my `spring` application (`spring rest + angular + mongo db`) to `cloud foundry` and I have this error.

> "Failed to push application - Client error - Error performing Cloud
>   Foundry operation : 502 Bad Gateway"

and I'm not sure if this problem from performance inside cloud foundry because I try the trial free or this is conflict in version of maven dependencies (in local it work properly) 
if someone has an idea

```
<java-version>1.6</java-version>
    <spring.version>3.2.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring.data.mongodb.version>1.1.1.RELEASE</spring.data.mongodb.version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.6.1</org.slf4j-version>
    <joda-time.version>1.6.2</joda-time.version>
    <jackson.version>1.8.1</jackson.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.mail.version> 1.4.3</java.mail.version>
    <org.cloudfoundry-version>0.8.5</org.cloudfoundry-version>
    <junit.version>4.8.2</junit.version>
    <spring.security.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
    <jersey.version>1.18.1</jersey.version>
```

Comment: Not enough information to tell. BTW the "tags" are for the parts that are "relevant" to your question and not for every aspect of the application you are working on. Probably simply tested by pushing a basic "hello world" and then adding dependencies until something breaks.

Comment: Thx @Neil Lunn for response, I tried a simple example and it works, but when I push a big project the problem appears.

Comment: So this is clearly a "pulling in dependencies problem" which is probably best resolved by "incrementally" adding dependencies until something breaks. I would also suggest you "should" be able access the "build" logs from your deployment, which will tell you exactly what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this has to do with your dependencies directly, although it's hard to say cause there's not much information to go on here.  Rather it's probably the size of what you're trying to upload and your upload speed.

When you're pushing an application you only have a finite amount of time to upload files, which if you're targeting run.pivotal.io (i.e PWS) is currently set at five minutes (it could be different on different systems).  After the five minutes expires, you'll get a 502 error.

You can work around this by uploading from somewhere with a faster connection or by uploading less information.

If you're targeting run.pivotal.io (i.e. PWS), we are in the process of raising this limit to 15 minutes which would give you the ability to upload more stuff with the same bandwidth.  I don't know exactly when this change will be made, but it's likely to go out in the next week or two.